# remove opacity to all images but one clicked with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I remove the opacity off all the elements which were not clicked. I have a set of images in a grid pattern. I'd like to be able to click anyone of them to get the rest to fade away. I can do it now but I'd like to have it be more dynamic.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#grid').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
   opacity: '0'.
   }, 1500, function() {
             });
         });
     });
 </script>

</head><body>

    <div class="portfolio">
     <ul id="grid">
       <li><a href="#"id="book"><img src="1.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book1"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book2"><img src="3.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book3"><img src="4.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book4"><img src="5.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book5"><img src="6.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book6"><img src="7.jpg"></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"id="book7"><img src="8.jpg"></a></li>   
       <li><a href="#"id="book8"><img src="9.jpg"></a></li>   
    </ul></div>
```

I'm thinking something like, 
if id does not contain id clicked opacity=0

Comment: ...and how do you plan to make them all again visible?

Comment: I'll just write another function to bring them back, trying to baby step it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need such a mess with IDs, keep it simple.

```
<div class="portfolio">
 <ul id="grid">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="1.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="2.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="3.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="4.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="5.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="6.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="7.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img src="8.jpg"></a></li>   
   <li><a href="#"><img src="9.jpg"></a></li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

every event (click in your case) is delegated to an element, known in JS as `target`.

jQuery for your case also has some nice selector as `.siblings()` which will target all other elements just not the current one.

```
$(function() { 
 $('#grid li').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings().animate({opacity: '0'}, 1500);
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cnjjx/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS? Maybe have two classes
    `img.clicked {
        opacity=1.0;
    }
    img.notClicked {
        opacity=0.0;
    }`
Then use jQuery to set the classes instead.